# Mysql Prepare Statement error while executing

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, concatenation

I am trying to create a table though prepare statement but it is giving me syntax error. Well if I try to execute the same statement individually then it works fine.

Here's my statement -

```
SET @Stmt1 = Concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',DB,'.`county`;\n'
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',DB,'.`County`
(
  `CountyID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CountyName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `CountyCode` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`CountyID`)
)');

Prepare stmt2 From @stmt1;
Execute stmt2;
```

Please can anyone tell me what am I missing in this statement? 
It is giving me an error on this line:

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',DB,'.`County`
(
  `CountyID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual error that you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/prepare.html says:

> The text [of the preparable statement] must represent a single SQL statement, not multiple statements.

So you'll have to execute your `DROP TABLE` statement first, and then prepare and execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement separately.

Answer (score 0):

are you not missing a comma between the two strings in the concat?

should be

```
SET @Stmt1 = Concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',DB,'.county;\n', 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',DB,'.County ( CountyID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, CountyName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, CountyCode VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CountyID) )');
```

Comment: is there any particular reason you're inserting a \n?

Comment: I'm just suspicious that's it's being interpreted literally in this case

Comment: It's easy to confirm in the mysql client:  select concat('abc', '\n', 'xyz');  Nope, the \n is translated into a newline.